# How to connect a mesos-slave (docker) to a mesos-master (vagrant)

Tags: docker, mesos

Both vagrant and docker are running on my laptop. I have created an issue on github @ https://github.com/mesosphere/playa-mesos/issues/34, but dont think my problem has been solved. Can someone please help me fix this ?
Here are the applicable logs :

Mesos-Master@Vagrant

```
    vagrant@mesos:~$ head -n 50 /var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO
    Log file created at: 2015/09/03 12:01:10
    Running on machine: mesos
    Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
    I0903 12:01:10.209606  7644 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
    I0903 12:01:10.210903  7644 main.cpp:181] Build: 2015-05-05 06:15:50 by root
    I0903 12:01:10.210978  7644 main.cpp:183] Version: 0.22.1
    I0903 12:01:10.211037  7644 main.cpp:186] Git tag: 0.22.1
    I0903 12:01:10.211099  7644 main.cpp:190] Git SHA: d6309f92a7f9af3ab61a878403e3d9c284ea87e0
    I0903 12:01:10.218832  7644 leveldb.cpp:176] Opened db in 7.325792ms
    I0903 12:01:10.222856  7644 leveldb.cpp:183] Compacted db in 3.902452ms
    I0903 12:01:10.222977  7644 leveldb.cpp:198] Created db iterator in 17600ns
    I0903 12:01:10.223202  7644 leveldb.cpp:204] Seeked to beginning of db in 15085ns
    I0903 12:01:10.223388  7644 leveldb.cpp:273] Iterated through 3 keys in the db in 71797ns
    I0903 12:01:10.223500  7644 replica.cpp:744] Replica recovered with log positions 111 -> 112 with 0 hole
    s and 0 unlearned
    I0903 12:01:10.226611  7644 main.cpp:306] Starting Mesos master
    I0903 12:01:10.226790  7665 log.cpp:238] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
    I0903 12:01:10.227406  7644 master.cpp:349] Master 20150903-120110-16842879-5050-7644 (10.141.141.10) st
    arted on 127.0.1.1:5050
    I0903 12:01:10.228006  7644 master.cpp:397] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
    I0903 12:01:10.228008  7664 recover.cpp:449] Starting replica recovery
    I0903 12:01:10.228238  7644 master.cpp:402] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
    I0903 12:01:10.228706  7669 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in VOTING status
    I0903 12:01:10.228780  7669 recover.cpp:464] Recover process terminated
    I0903 12:01:10.254407  7669 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(4)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeepe
    r
    I0903 12:01:10.254457  7669 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas)
    = (0, 0, 0)
    I0903 12:01:10.254485  7669 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.255058  7664 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(3)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeepe
    r
    I0903 12:01:10.255980  7664 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas)
    = (0, 0, 0)
    I0903 12:01:10.256007  7664 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.256227  7665 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(2)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeepe
    r
    I0903 12:01:10.256260  7665 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas)
    = (1, 0, 0)
    I0903 12:01:10.256283  7665 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.257098  7662 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeepe
    r
    I0903 12:01:10.258298  7662 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas)
    = (0, 0, 0)
    I0903 12:01:10.258332  7662 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.264096  7668 master.cpp:1295] Successfully attached file '/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INF
    O'
    I0903 12:01:10.264139  7668 contender.cpp:131] Joining the ZK group
    I0903 12:01:10.291113  7669 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='29')
    I0903 12:01:10.291247  7669 group.cpp:659] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000029' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.291667  7665 contender.cpp:247] New candidate (id='29') has entered the contest for leade
    rship
    I0903 12:01:10.300559  7662 network.hpp:424] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
    I0903 12:01:10.300688  7662 group.cpp:659] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000029' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.340422  7669 detector.cpp:452] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is detec
    ted
    I0903 12:01:10.340517  7669 master.cpp:1356] The newly elected leader is master@127.0.1.1:5050 with id 2
    0150903-120110-16842879-5050-7644
    I0903 12:01:10.340556  7669 master.cpp:1369] Elected as the leading master!
    I0903 12:01:10.340584  7669 master.cpp:1187] Recovering from registrar
    I0903 12:01:10.340657  7669 registrar.cpp:313] Recovering registrar
    I0903 12:01:10.340950  7669 log.cpp:660] Attempting to start the writer
    I0903 12:01:10.345010  7662 group.cpp:659] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000030' in ZooKeeper
    I0903 12:01:10.372704  7663 replica.cpp:477] Replica received implicit promise request with proposal 29
    I0903 12:01:10.376240  7662 network.hpp:466] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@127.0.1.1:5050 }
    vagrant@mesos:~$
```

Mesos-Slave@Docker

```
root@6ed9553b22b3:/tmp# head -n 50 /var/log/mesos/slave/mesos-slave.INFO
Log file created at: 2015/09/01 03:16:18
Running on machine: 6ed9553b22b3
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0901 03:16:18.957794     1 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0901 03:16:18.960610     1 main.cpp:142] Build: 2014-11-22 05:29:57 by root
I0901 03:16:18.960901     1 main.cpp:144] Version: 0.21.0
I0901 03:16:18.961180     1 main.cpp:147] Git tag: 0.21.0
I0901 03:16:18.961447     1 main.cpp:151] Git SHA: ab8fa655d34e8e15a4290422df38a18db1c09b5b
I0901 03:16:18.962405     1 containerizer.cpp:100] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem
I0901 03:16:18.969552     1 main.cpp:165] Starting Mesos slave
I0901 03:16:18.981950     1 slave.cpp:169] Slave started on 1)@172.17.0.12:5051
I0901 03:16:18.985064     1 slave.cpp:289] Slave resources: cpus(*):4; mem(*):497; disk(*):13483; ports
*):[31000-32000]
I0901 03:16:18.992239     1 slave.cpp:318] Slave hostname: 6ed9553b22b3
I0901 03:16:18.992740     1 slave.cpp:319] Slave checkpoint: true
I0901 03:16:19.049140    12 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@172.17.0.12:5051) connected to ZooKe
per
I0901 03:16:19.060787    12 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas)
= (0, 0, 0)
I0901 03:16:19.062479    12 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0901 03:16:19.085188     7 state.cpp:33] Recovering state from '/var/lib/mesos/slave/meta'
I0901 03:16:19.091830     7 state.cpp:62] Failed to find the latest slave from '/var/lib/mesos/slave/me
a'
I0901 03:16:19.096117     7 status_update_manager.cpp:197] Recovering status update manager
I0901 03:16:19.098574     7 containerizer.cpp:281] Recovering containerizer
I0901 03:16:19.111192     7 slave.cpp:3466] Finished recovery
I0901 03:16:19.204704    12 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='15')
I0901 03:16:19.217427    12 group.cpp:659] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000015' in ZooKeeper
I0901 03:16:19.268682    12 detector.cpp:433] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is dete
ted
I0901 03:16:19.270802    12 status_update_manager.cpp:171] Pausing sending status updates
I0901 03:16:19.270815     6 slave.cpp:602] New master detected at master@127.0.1.1:5050
I0901 03:16:19.275054     6 slave.cpp:627] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without auth
ntication
I0901 03:16:19.276578     6 slave.cpp:638] Detecting new master
I0901 03:16:19.279539     7 slave.cpp:2623] master@127.0.1.1:5050 exited
W0901 03:16:19.279961     7 slave.cpp:2626] Master disconnected! Waiting for a new master to be elected
I0901 03:17:19.033237     8 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:17:24.227412    10 detector.cpp:138] Detected a new leader: (id='16')
I0901 03:17:24.233980    13 group.cpp:659] Trying to get '/mesos/info_0000000016' in ZooKeeper
I0901 03:17:24.313081    13 detector.cpp:433] A new leading master (UPID=master@127.0.1.1:5050) is dete
ted
I0901 03:17:24.318869     9 status_update_manager.cpp:171] Pausing sending status updates
I0901 03:17:24.315673    13 slave.cpp:602] New master detected at master@127.0.1.1:5050
I0901 03:17:24.322504    13 slave.cpp:627] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without auth
ntication
I0901 03:17:24.339941    13 slave.cpp:638] Detecting new master
I0901 03:17:24.400082    13 slave.cpp:2623] master@127.0.1.1:5050 exited
W0901 03:17:24.401018    13 slave.cpp:2626] Master disconnected! Waiting for a new master to be elected
I0901 03:18:19.059062    13 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:19:19.128324    12 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:20:19.142246     8 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:21:19.157043    12 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:22:19.177832     6 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:23:19.244776     7 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:24:19.265439    12 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:25:19.277276    10 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
I0901 03:26:19.314956    11 slave.cpp:3321] Current usage 93.89%. Max allowed age: 0ns
root@6ed9553b22b3:/tmp#
```

Telnet results:
Mesos-Slave@Docker -> Mesos-Master@Vagrant

```
root@6ed9553b22b3:/tmp# telnet 10.141.141.10 5050
Trying 10.141.141.10...
Connected to 10.141.141.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Mesos-Master@Vagrant -> Mesos-Slave@Docker

```
vagrant@mesos:~$ telnet 192.168.59.104 5051
Trying 192.168.59.104...
Connected to 192.168.59.104.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
vagrant@mesos:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your master start in ip1:5050, slave start in ip2:5051. Could the slave telnet to ip1:5050 success? Could the master telnet to ip:5051 success? If both these success, the slave should could connect to master as normal. If still could not, please paste master/slave logs.

Comment: Yes, telnet works for both the scenarios you have asked. But I dont see the (docker) `mesos-slave` in the (vagrant) `mesos-master` when I navigate to the `mesos-master` 5050 webui console.

Comment: Could you provide slave and master log?

Comment: Do you mean as inline text or links to filesharing websites ? I don't use the latter .... I have only INFO level logs turned on. There is also a mesos-slave running on vagrant and this is for marathon. I am assuming you meant the docker mesos-slave, right ?

Comment: Yes, I mean mesos-slave.

Comment: Both of these are fairly large to copy+paste here in s/o. Do you want a `head` or `tail` with specific number of lines instead for each of these logs ?

Comment: I have updated the main post above with first 50 lines of respective logs and also provided the telnet results as requested by you.

Comment: You master is listen in  "master@127.0.1.1:5050" I think you need start master with --ip 10.141.141.10

Comment: The config file for vagrant has the `ip_address` set to 10.141.141.10, Please see https://github.com/mesosphere/playa-mesos/blob/master/config.json.

Comment: Because your master log have something like
```
I0903 12:01:10.254485  7669 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0903 12:01:10.255058  7664 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(3)@127.0.1.1:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
```
So I sure it is not start with a public ip.

Comment: I don't know how playa-meos and mesos-deb-packaging works exactly. But when I check mesosphere  [mesos-init-wrapper](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging/blob/master/mesos-init-wrapper), seems only when you `export IP=10.141.141.10` before you start mesos-master, then the master would run as this public ip. So could you ssh to vagrant, and then  `export IP=10.141.141.10` and restart mesos-master and mesos-slave.

Comment: Stil doesn't work with that. I tried it and I still see the log file for the mesos-master trying to connect to the vagrant-zookeeper and also starting itself and the vagrant-mesos-slave locally. Does the docker-mesos-slave ipaddr need to be configured in the vagrant-mesos env ?

Comment: I think, I will turn off all vagrant based mesos services like mesos-slave, marathon and chronos, keeping only the mesos-master running. Do you think this will be worth investigating with this setup ? With that, here is  a netstat for 2181 and 5050 on vagrant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88833/discussion-between-zerograviti-and-haosdent).